# String format limit significant digits Swift

Tags: swift

I need to convert a Double to String with a limit on max number of digits in Swift.  I am using the following to limit the digits after decimal to 2.

```
numberString = String(format: "%.02f", 0.4394)
```

How to do something similar but limit the whole number to 5 digits i.e. 9438.45 to 9438.5

Comment: What do you mean you want to limit the whole number to 5 digits? If it's .4394, it should appear as .43940?

Comment: @SShahid no, but if its more than 5 I want 5 max

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using `NumberFormatter` and setting its `maximumSignificantDigits` property:

```
let fmt = NumberFormatter()
fmt.numberStyle = .decimal
//fmt.minimumSignificantDigits = 5 // optional depending on needs
fmt.maximumSignificantDigits = 5

var n = 0.43578912

for _ in 0..<5 {
    print(fmt.string(for: n)!)
    n *= 10
}
```

Output:

> 0.43579
>   4.3579
>   43.579
>   435.79
>   4,357.9

You can specify other formatting options as desired such as disabling the grouping separator.

Setting `minimumSignificantDigits` will be useful if you want trailing zeros with numbers that have fewer digits.

Comment: Anyway to remove the comma?

Comment: @bakalolo Of course. I mentioned that possibility in my answer. Simply add `fmt.usesGroupingSeparator = false`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "g" format specifier:

```
var n = 0.4354345

for i in 0..<5 {
    print(String(format: "%5g", n))
    n = n * 10
}
```

will give you:

```
0.435435
4.35435
43.5435
435.435
4354.35
```

Your next best option is going to be to convert and then fix up by truncating the string.

Comment: It's odd that `%5` results in 6 significant digits.

Comment: I got nothing @rmaddy  It's been that way for decades :)

Comment: This did not work for me it seems like whatever number I put in front of g still results in 6 digits.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what's up with that, but it seems like the swift `String(format:)` function doesn't actually work like the c/c++ printf it mimics where a precision specifier on 'g' or 'G' specifies the number of significant digits to print.